# Not showing all values in arraylist

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, arraylist

I am trying to show some values in jsp page using arraylist but its showing all the values except the top row values. Here is what I have written as my code.

```
    <table border="1">
    <tr>
    <th>Book ID</th>
    <th>Branch ID</th>
    <th>Card No.</th>
    <th>Date Out</th>
    <th>Due Date</th>
    </tr>
    
    <%
    LibModel lm=(LibModel)request.getAttribute("data");
    for(int a=0;a<lm.branch_id.size();a++) {
    %>
    <tr>
    <td><%= lm.book_ids.get(a)%></td>
    <td><%= lm.branch_id.get(a)%></td>
    <td><%= lm.cards.get(a)%></td>
    <td><%= lm.date_out.get(a)%></td>
    <td><%= lm.due_date.get(a)%></td>

  </tr>
<% }%>
 </table>
```

I am giving input

book id = 721
card no = 900

my query supports sub-string matching.

It should show

## Book ID   Branch ID   Card No   Date Out   Due Date

72127317    1         9009     2013-11-25  2013-12-09

72127317    3         9009     2013-11-25  2013-12-09

but its showing just

## Book ID   Branch ID   Card No   Date Out   Due Date

72127317    3         9009     2013-11-25  2013-12-09

Comment: Have you verified by unit testing that the correct array is returned by your filtering code?

Comment: No i didn't. I am getting the same value there also which I am getting here. Might be some there is some problem with earlier coding. Thanks for making me do this.